# Check Div Elements by name fast

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have some Divs:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="c" id="1">
        <div id="xyz">dont care</div>
        <div id="texts1">
            <div name="check"> ContentText </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c" id="2">
        <div id="xuyz">dont care</div>
        <div id="texts2">
            <div name="check"> ContentText </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to iterate through all elements of the "c" class.
Then I want to check, if the Div elements named "check" of each "c" element contains special text.

If true, then manipulate the "c" element (which contains the special text)

I tried something like this:

```
var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("c");
for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++)
{
 var check = ele[i].getElementsByName("check");
 if(check.innerHTML ....)
}
```

But thats not working :/
Log from Firefox:

```
TypeError: ele[i].getElementsByName is not a function
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Oh yeah - ofc. It was just a mistake in that quick example. Second div "c" has id 2 ;D

Comment: Why are you using a `name` on a `div`?

Comment: Why is this tagged with jQuery?

Comment: And in your loop, I think you could just use `getAttribute("name")` to save time: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute

Comment: Maybe it can be solved with jquery very quickly?

Comment: Only `document` has `getElementsByName` method, not elements.

Comment: @CullenJ, but i want to look at the Elements with the name Attribute = "check".

Comment: If you want to use jQuery, you can use the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/): `$('[name="check"]')`

Comment: @Teemu Thank you very much :) That was my mistake.
Argh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) should do the trick:

```
var check = document.querySelectorAll('.c [name="check"]');
```

And as stated in a comment already, only `document` has `getElementsByName` method.

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery this is very simple -

```
$('[name="check"]:contains("your special text")')
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery (you have tagged it with it as well)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.c').find('div[name="check"]').each(function(){
        // here check HTML and do needed manipulations
        if($(this).html() == 'ContentText'){
            $(this).closest('div.c').children().first().html('I CARE');
        }
    });
});
```

see jSFiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/ApfJz/32/

Comment: have to be careful with this because the html must exactly match (including spaces). In your example I changed the if to look for "ContentText2" and it didn't work, I had to change it to " ContentText2 "

Comment: yes you are right but data in that example was not so important, the main target was to detect correct elements in DOM and later on, depends on what person asking for help wanted to achieve do correct conditional checks and manipulations

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modification of your code to make it work as intended

```
var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("c");
for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++)
{
    if (ele[i].getAttribute('name') === "check") {
        // do something with matching elements here
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops, this is wrong... you're looking for children of the `div` elemenets with the `c` class... I thought you were looking for this `<div class="c" name="check">`. Let me know if you're still stuck on this, but I believe Teemu's answer will work for you.